# Disk partition structure

Tags: java, file, structure, disk, disk-partitioning

Is there *any* way in Java (1.6+) to retrieve the partition disk structure? (For example: NTFS, FAT32, HFS+, or EXT3.)

External libraries are permitted.

Thanks,
Gianni

Comment: Do you mean partition table of the hard disk (like in the question)? Or the programmatic access to file system information (like the abbr. in parantheses suggest)?

Comment: Yes, something like `String value = MySystem.getPartitionStructure();` and on Mac OS X the string  `value` would be  `HFS+`.

Comment: It's going to be platform dependent, I think.

Comment: I thing so, I've started writing it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to execute a command like sfdisk and then parse the output.

```
sfdisk -l /dev/hdc
```

Unfortunately, it isn't very platform independent.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of writing a class that would execute system dependent commands and extract the information I need from it. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel, you see. If there is a Java library that could do it for me, I don't need to code it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under OS X the output of "mount" includes the file system:

```
ravn:~ ravn$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

Here `/` is of type `hfs`

Comment: Well, I was thinking of writing a class that would execute system dependent commands and extract the information I need from it. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel, you see. If there is a Java library that could do it for me, I don't need to code it myself. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently nobody needs it.  Why do you?

Comment: I'm writing a program and it needs the disk structure. Like I've said above, I've already started writing my own library.

Comment: Please be specific.  _WHY_ does it need to know the disk structure?

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question. The point is I need to print the disk structure. My Java app doesn't need to know it, the user needs it.

Comment: Then showing the user the complete output from "mount <location>" on Unix is probably the best, as this ensures that your library assumes as little as possible about the actual output format which varies between systems.  Have fun.

Comment: I think so. I'm writing my own library right now. It is already working on unix, mac and linux.

Answer (score 1):

If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037850/any-open-source-ntfs-fat32-hfs-or-ext-implementations-in-java) doesn't help then - no. You'll need a native library and some OS dependent code for it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't like the technique described in that thread.